# ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object - Other Forums are not Assisting Me

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am running into an error that I cannot seem to correct.

Here is my code. I have no other code. I have tried the code in APEX and LiveSQL. My code is typed out in the proper format but my post won't format it how I want it to, so I apologize. Any help is appreciated.

The goal of my code is to do the following:

Write an SQL statement to create the below table.

[image: See Table Image]

```
CREATE TABLE grocery_items
   (product_id NUMBER(3),
   brand VARCHAR2(20),
   description VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO grocery_items (product_id, brand, description)
VALUES (110, 'Colgate', 'Toothpaste');
INSERT INTO grocery_items (product_id, brand, description)
VALUES (111, 'Ivory', 'Soap');
INSERT INTO grocery_items (product_id, brand, description)
VALUES (112, 'Heinz', 'Ketchup');
```

Comment: What are the results of this query: `SELECT
  table_name, owner
FROM
  user_tables
ORDER BY
  owner, table_name`

Comment: I'm really sorry but what do you mean what are the results? I don't get any results that I know of because I am unable to get past the error...I apologize again that I am misunderstanding.

Comment: Please execute the query I provided and return the results.

Comment: You can use this query as well: `SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

Comment: Wow, I am so sorry about that. This is the result that I got: ORA-00904: "OWNER": invalid identifier

Comment: This is the result of the second query: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: Can you break your query into pieces to identify on which line the error occurs?

Comment: You don't have permissions to query against the information_schema then. Do you have the ability to grant your self elevated permissions or use the `SYS` account?

Comment: I do not believe I have those permissions...I am in school and they give us limited permissions in the application.

Comment: the table that you're trying to create is already existed, use `SELECT * FROM grocery_items` to check of its existing. if is it existed, then just use `INSERT` as there is no need to create the table.

Comment: Oh my gosh! Thank you so much! That made it work. It was that simple. I didn't even think to use *. I appreciate your help greatly!

Comment: also - what other forums are you trying?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you are running the script twice or more. That means the table still exists from the first run.  To make this a reunable script add a drop before your create.

```
SQL> drop TABLE grocery_items;

Table GROCERY_ITEMS dropped.

SQL> CREATE TABLE grocery_items
  2     (product_id NUMBER(3),
  3     brand VARCHAR2(20),
  4     description VARCHAR(20));

Table GROCERY_ITEMS created.

SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO grocery_items (product_id, brand, description)
  2  VALUES (110, 'Colgate', 'Toothpaste');

1 row inserted.

SQL> INSERT INTO grocery_items (product_id, brand, description)
  2  VALUES (111, 'Ivory', 'Soap');

1 row inserted.

SQL> INSERT INTO grocery_items (product_id, brand, description)
  2  VALUES (112, 'Heinz', 'Ketchup');

1 row inserted.

SQL> select * from grocery_items;

PRODUCT_ID BRAND                DESCRIPTION         
---------- -------------------- --------------------
       110 Colgate              Toothpaste          
       111 Ivory                Soap                
       112 Heinz                Ketchup             

SQL>
```

Comment: This is so helpful! Thank you so much!

Comment: Great glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CREATE` SQL statement is OK.

The error is seem like `grocery_items` already exist in your DB.

Try use only `INSERT` statement.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/322ab/2)

Comment: So I don't understand why that is/how to fix it. I uploaded over 30,000 schema/scripts which should match all the code I write...I am so sorry for being so new to this. I am just highly confused as to how to correct it.